# Parsing data from a child element in an xml document

Tags: c#, xml

I'm having difficulty parsing a sub element from an xml document.

The document contains a series of elements containing pricing information that I need to extract the Euro price from. No matter what I do, I can't seem to extract the data that I need. The result is always null.

```
<departure>
    <pricing xmlns="http://website.com/api/feeds/xmlns/20110926/">
      <price age_group="Adult" label="1 Adult" max_age="100" max_passengers="100" min_age="12" min_passengers="1">
        <USD>4249.00</USD>
        <AUD>4299.00</AUD>
        <CHF>3649.00</CHF>
        <GBP>2749.00</GBP>
        <NZD>5399.00</NZD>
        <CAD>4399.00</CAD>
        <EUR>3249.00</EUR> <------------this is what I need to parse
      </price>
    </pricing>
    <pricing xmlns="http://website.com/api/feeds/xmlns/20110926/">
      <price age_group="Adult" label="1 Adult" max_age="100" max_passengers="100" min_age="12" min_passengers="1">
        <USD>4249.00</USD>
        <AUD>4299.00</AUD>
        <CHF>3649.00</CHF>
        <GBP>2749.00</GBP>
        <NZD>5399.00</NZD>
        <CAD>4399.00</CAD>
        <EUR>3249.00</EUR> <------------this is what I need to parse
      </price>
    </pricing>
<departure>


XmlNodeList departureNodes = xmlDoc.GetElementsByTagName("departure");
if (departureNodes.Count > 0)
{
    foreach (XmlElement element in departureNodes)
    {
        string priceInEUR = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("pricing/price/EUR"); // returns null
        string priceInEUR2 = xmlElement.SelectSingleNode("//pricing/price/EUR"); // also returns null
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to use XDocument and Linq to XML.

```
using System.Xml.Linq;

IEnumerable<XElement> prices = from t in doc.Root.Descendants("EUR");
    foreach (XElement t in prices)
    {
        string priceInEUR = t.Value;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The way I have this document here: http://searisen.com/xmllib/extensions.wiki

You can currently do: (presuming departure is a child of the root node)

```
decimal[] euros = XElement.Load(xmlFile)
              .GetEnumerable("departure/pricing",
                 x => x.Get("price/EUR", decimal.MinValue))
              .ToArray();
```

This gets all the euros, the two you have listed.